# I usually come from the south, What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I usually come from the south,
>
> A howdy comes from my mouth.
>
> But then I come from the north,
>
> Or skywards from the earth.
>
> I may be a jolly old jerk,
>
> Or even a delay, at work.

What am I?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This might be...

> **Hiccup**

I usually come from the south,
A howdy comes from my mouth.

> A **hick** is an American derogatory term for a Southerner

But then I come from the north,
Or skywards from the earth.

> Followed by **up** (up north or going up)

I may be a jolly old jerk,

> A hiccup is an involuntary muscle *jerk* (but can be considered amusing)

Or even a delay, at work.

> ...And the word also means a small *delay*.

Comment: Wow!! great job.